# How to bind SharePoint:FormField with data coming from a string array on server side?

Tags: 2010, javascript, custom-list, custom-form, dropdown

```
<SharePoint:FormField 
                runat="server" 
                ID="field_Domain" 
                ControlMode="New" 
                FieldName="Domain"/>
```

I want to fill the formfield above with data comming from an array of string.
The context: a list custom form (New), sharepoint 2010.

The control is part of the .ascx of a webpart used to create a list custom new form. The data processing is done in the code behind (.cs).

Comment: Aren't you missing any words in the question?? Not able to get the context  of your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "business" (I'm also still new at sharepoint). But you can always update or add items to dropdowns by Javascript.

Something like this:

```
ReplaceDropDown = function() {
    var apiCallUrl = '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Your List\')/items?$top=1000';   
    $.ajax({
        url: apiCallUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },

        success: function(jsonData){
            if(jsonData.d.results[0] != null){  
                $("[title='Member Association']").empty();                      
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.d.results.length; i++) {
                    var selectedHTM = (currentId == jsonData.d.results[i].ID) ? 'selected="selected"': '';
                    $("[title='Your List']").append('<option ' + selectedHTM + 'value="' + jsonData.d.results[i].ID + '">' + jsonData.d.results[i].Title + '</option>');
                }

            }   
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("An error occured..." + data.responseText);
        }   
    });     
}
```

This is an example where you load the content of the dropdown out of another SP List with a REST Call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to get data from a string array. The array is instantiate inside the code behind. I wasn't clear enough. My bad.

Comment: So just use your Array. Actually it's almost the same:

`for (var i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAY.length; i++) {
 var selectedHTM = (currentd == i) ? 'selected="selected"': '';
 $("[title='Your List']").append('<option ' + selectedHTM + 'value="' + i + '">' + YOUR_ARRAY[i] + '</option>');
}`

Comment: I just want to fill my formfield with an array of string declared in the code behind. I don't want to get a sharepoint list sorry.

Comment: This is what the above method does:
It fills a given form select field with an array.

More simplyfied:
`for (var i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAY.length; i++) { 
 $("#field_fieldName").append('<option ' + selectedHTM + 'value="' + YOUR_ARRAY[i] + '">' + YOUR_ARRAY[i] + '</option>'); 
}`

Comment: As I said the array is coming from the code behind so there is no way for me to access it.

Comment: Actually I still don't understand the problem... You have an array (where-ever it comes from) and you want to fill a dropdownlist with the content of this array???

Comment: Yes. I'll trying to be more specific. How can I get my string array values from the code behind, using jquery to populate my formfield ?

Comment: OK... Where does this "code behind" come from? Could you please post some code here and  be more specific and give us a little bit more context?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge i can suggest you these 2 methods. But if you have better one then please let me know also.

1) You should try saving that array with some special characters like '*' or something in the HiddenField and later on split that value using that special character and bind your dropdown. In this case if you are not getting value from hidden field as your HiddenField will be server control then try delaying you javascript method. To read server control's value you have use its ClientID.

2) OR else you have create a REST/Webservice which will return that Array of string then call that Service and on success bind your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Field` property of the form field (field_Domain) which returns an SPField object and cast it to your actual field type on the form and then set the values from your string array.